# Cloning an object and saving the clone to db causes the original object to lose relational data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

When I'm trying to clone a `Product`-object and save the clone to the database, the original object loses all it's relational data, such as `ProductPropertyOptionForProducts`, `IdentifierForProducts` and `InCategories`.

This is the Product model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductGroupId { get; set; }
    public int ProductGroupSortOrder { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(30), MinLength(4)]     public string Title { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200)]                            public string Info { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(4000)]                           public string LongInfo { get; set; }
    [Required, DataType(DataType.Currency)]     public decimal Price { get; set; }
                                                public int Weight { get; set; }
                                                public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductImage> Images { get; set; }

    // Selected property options for this product
    public ICollection<PropertyOptionForProduct> ProductPropertyOptionForProducts { get; set; }

    // A product can have multiple identifiers (EAN, ISBN, product number, etc.)
    public ICollection<IdentifierForProduct> IdentifierForProducts { get; set; }

    public ProductType Type { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FrontPageProduct> InFrontPages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductInCategory> InCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Some of the related models:

```
public class ProductInCategory
// A linking table for which products belongs to which categories
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    // Nav.props.:
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyOptionForProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductPropertyId { get; set; }
    public int ProductPropertyOptionId { get; set; }

    // Nav.props.
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductPropertyOption ProductPropertyOption { get; set; }
}

public class IdentifierForProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductIdentifierId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30), MaxLength(30)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ProductIdentifier ProductIdentifier { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

The original is loaded like this:

```
public async Task<Product> GetProduct(int Id)
{
    Product DbM = await _context.Products
        .Include(ic => ic.InCategories)
            .ThenInclude(pc => pc.ProductCategory)
        .Include(t => t.Type)
            .ThenInclude(iit => iit.Identifiers) //ProductIdentifiersInTypes
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Identifier) // ProductIdentifiers
                    .ThenInclude(ifp => ifp.ProductIdentifiers) // IdentifiersForProducts
        .Include(t => t.Type)
            .ThenInclude(pit => pit.Properties) // ProductPropertiesInTypes
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Property) // ProductProperties
                    .ThenInclude(po => po.Options) // ProductPropertyOptions
        .Include(p => p.ProductPropertyOptionForProducts)
        .Where(p => p.Id == Id)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    return DbM;
}
```

This is the clone-method:

```
private async Task<Product> MakeClone(Product Original)
{
    Product Clone = new Product
    {
        ProductGroupId = Original.ProductGroupId,
        ProductGroupSortOrder = Original.ProductGroupSortOrder + 1,
        IdentifierForProducts = Original.IdentifierForProducts,
        Images = Original.Images,
        InCategories = Original.InCategories,
        Info = Original.Info,
        InFrontPages = Original.InFrontPages,
        LongInfo = Original.LongInfo,
        Price = Original.Price,
        ProductPropertyOptionForProducts = Original.ProductPropertyOptionForProducts,
        ProductTypeId = Original.ProductTypeId,
        Title = Original.Title,
        Type = Original.Type,
        Weight = Original.Weight
    };
    _context.Add(Clone);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Clone; // and go to the Edit-view.
}
```

Now, the clone has all the properties of the original product, but the original has been stripped of all of it's relational data. In the database, it looks like the clone's relational data has replaced the original's ones.

**UPDATE**

In accordance to Georg's answer, I changed my `MakeClone()`-method to this:

```
private Product MakeClone(Product Original)
{
    List<IdentifierForProduct> identifiers = Original
            .IdentifierForProducts
            .Select(i => CloneIdentifierForProduct(i))
            .ToList();
    List<PropertyOptionForProduct> propertyOptions = Original
            .ProductPropertyOptionForProducts
            .Select(o => ClonePropertyOptionForProduct(o))
            .ToList();
    List<ProductInCategory> inCategories = Original
            .InCategories
            .Select(c => CloneProductInCategory(c))
            .ToList();
    List<FrontPageProduct> inFrontPages = Original
            .InFrontPages
            .Select(f => CloneFrontPageProduct(f))
            .ToList();
    List<ProductImage> images = Original.Images.Select(i => CloneProductImage(i)).ToList();
    Product Clone = new Product
    {
        ProductGroupId = Original.ProductGroupId,
        ProductGroupSortOrder = Original.ProductGroupSortOrder + 1,
        Info = Original.Info,
        LongInfo = Original.LongInfo,
        Price = Original.Price,
        ProductTypeId = Original.ProductTypeId,
        Title = Original.Title,
        Type = Original.Type,
        Weight = Original.Weight,
        IdentifierForProducts = identifiers,
        ProductPropertyOptionForProducts = propertyOptions,
        InCategories = inCategories,
        InFrontPages = inFrontPages,
        Images = images
    };
    _context.Add(Clone);
    // fix FKs
    foreach (var ifp in Clone.IdentifierForProducts) ifp.ProductId = Clone.Id;
    foreach (var ofp in Clone.ProductPropertyOptionForProducts) ofp.ProductId = Clone.Id;
    foreach (var pic in Clone.InCategories) pic.ProductId = Clone.Id;
    foreach (var fpp in Clone.InFrontPages) fpp.ProductId = Clone.Id;
    foreach (var pi in Clone.Images) pi.ProductId = Clone.Id;
    // Lagre klonen i databasen:
    _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Clone;
}
```

... and added separate methods for cloning each of the linked data (I don't think I need to show all five methods):

```
private IdentifierForProduct CloneIdentifierForProduct(IdentifierForProduct ifp)
{
    IdentifierForProduct IFP = new IdentifierForProduct
    {
        Product = ifp.Product,
        ProductId = ifp.ProductId,
        ProductIdentifier = ifp.ProductIdentifier,
        ProductIdentifierId = ifp.ProductIdentifierId,
        Value = ifp.Value
    };
    return IFP;
}
```

Now I'm getting `ArgumentNullException` on the creation of the child Lists.

Could it have something to do with the fact that for example `IdentifierForProduct` also has a child property (which I also want to clone)?

Comment: How are `InCategories` (as an example) linked to those objects? Is there a foreign key column in that table?

Comment: Cloning an object is a complex procedure. For example here you are not cloning all the IEnumerables but just copying their reference in the new object. I am not sure if this is ok when you pass everything to the entity framework

Comment: Can you check whether `Original` has `ProductPropertyOptionForProducts` and other properties? If not then you have to use `Include(x => x.ProductPropertyOptionForProducts)` and so on and If yes then use `AutoMapper` for cloning complex objects. How are you creating `Original` before calling `MakeClone` method?.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen See updated question. I have added some of the linked models. The rest of them also follows the same pattern.

Comment: @viveknuna Please see my updated question. I have added the `GetProduct()`-method, which is how the original product is loaded.

Comment: @Steve Yes, I think you have a good point. How can I clone the IEnumerables, and not just their references?

Comment: `IdentifierForProducts` should also be `new` while cloning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Steve noted, you are just setting a reference to the collection properties of the original, instead of cloning the collection. If the relationship of the collection is not defined as many:many, this removes the related entities from the original and adds them to the clone.

For example, to clone the `IdentifierForProducts` collection, you have to clone each element and then add them to the collection of the clone.

```
Product clone = new Product {
    IdentifierForProducts = Original.IdentifierForProducts.Select(ifp => MakeClone(ifp)).ToList(),
    // other properties ....
};

// fix FKs after cloning
foreach (var ifp in clone.IdentifierForProducts) {
    ifp.ProductId = clone.Id;
}
```

with `MakeClone<IdentifierForProduct>(IdentifierForProduct original)` analogous to `MakeClone<Product>(Product original)`.

Comment: I may have been too quick to accept your answer... Your suggestion gives me the exception `InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

Comment: Is this exception thrown in the `foreach`?

Comment: It is thrown on this line: `Product Clone = new Product`.

Comment: I tried this approach in a [C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b8XFHC) and it seems to work in principle. Do you use a `foreach` inside any of the `CloneXXX()` methods? This exception normally occurs if you change the collection you are looping over (something like this `foreach (var elem in theCollection) { theCollection.Remove(elem); }` or `foreach (var elem in theCollection) { var newElem = new X(elem); theCollection.Add(newElem); }`).

Comment: I understand. So strange. No, there is no `foreach`, other than when fixing the FKs after the cloning. My code is as in the question, after the **UPDATE**, except, I have removed `async` and `await`.

Comment: Now I'm getting `ArgumentNullException` on the creation of the child Lists. Could it have something to do with the fact that for example `IdentifierForProduct` also has a child property (which I also want to clone)?

Comment: This `ArgumentNullException` is probably caused by a source list that is null. Try to add a null check: `IdentifierForProducts = Original.IdentifierForProducts?.Select(ifp => MakeClone(ifp)).ToList() ?? new List<IdentifierForProducts>()`

Comment: That did indeed help. Now, the product is being cloned, but I get a **HTTP Error 500**. When I navigate back to the product page, the new clone is there. Any idea what the 500-error could be about? I will accept your answer now, as this new error is probably not related to the issue of my original question. :)